# 'variantToString' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, string, qt, variant

I'm busy following a tutorial where I'm creating an `XMLExport` class using C++ with Qt.

I've run into some issues with this line of code:

```
result += QString (
    "%1 <property name=\"%2\" type=\"%3\" value=\"%4\" />"
    ).arg(indentspace).arg(propname).arg(qv.typeName())
    .arg(variantToString(qv))
```

The problem is specifically at `.arg(variantToString(qv));`.

When I attempt to build the project I get the following built error:

> 'variantToString' was not declared in this scope:
>
> ```
> .arg(variantToString(qv));
>                        ^
> ```

Any help here on a solution would be much appreciated!

Comment: Don't you want [`qv.toString()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#toString) instead?

Comment: That fixed it thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `variantToString(qv)` with `qv.toString()`:

```
result += QString (
    "%1 <property name=\"%2\" type=\"%3\" value=\"%4\" />"
    ).arg(indentspace).arg(propname).arg(qv.typeName())
    .arg(qv.toString())
```